# Need help creating Quiz App- how to put image ?? Xcode (iphone)

Tags: c, xcode, image

I am new to App Developing. I am creating an App Quiz game. In the quiz there are two Categories. In the first Category, I have created Category to Guess through image.

I Have Game.h and Game.m files. And I want image instead of a question to be display. I need help, how can I put code of image before that.

```
#import "Game.h"

@interface Game ()

@end

@implementation Game

-(void) Category1{
    switch (QuestionSelected) {
        case 0:

            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Answer1" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Answer2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"Answer3" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks nobody answered, I managed myself to solve this. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by putting this code:

Thanks

```
Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

-(void) Category1{

```
switch (imageQuestionSelected) {
    case 0:
     imageQuestion.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iamge.png"];
```